# Dataset for density based clustering based on probability and possible cluster validation method

Tags: statistics, dataset, cluster-analysis, probability, survey

Can anyone help me to  find a dataset have scores as attribute values and having the class labels(Ground Truth for cluster validation).I want to find the probability of each data item and inturn use it for clustering.

The preferable attribute values are scores like user survey scores(1-bad,2-satisfactory,3-good,4-very good) for each of the attributes.I am preferring score values(say 1,2,3,4) as  attribute values as it is easy to calculate probability of each attribute value from these score values.

I found some datasets from UCI Repository but not all attribute values were score values.

Comment: I would also like to get a suggestion regarding the following issue.....I am aiming at applying density based clustering on such a dataset. I suppose that internal cluster validation indices like cohesion and seperation will not show good results on such density based approaches ,also I found that clustering as it is an exploratory approach will not give correct class labels.So which sort of an approach should I use to evalute the clusters produced from such a clustering. Is there any mistakes in my understanding of  the clustering/validation approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) clustering algorithms are density based.

There is plenty of survey literature on clustering algorithm that you need to check. There are literary hundreds of density based algorithms, including DBSCAN, OPTICS, DENCLUE, ...

However, I have the impression you are using the term "density based" different than literature. You seem to refer to probability, not density?

Do not expect clustering to give class labels. Classes are not clusters. Classes can be inseparable, or a single class may consists of multiple clusters. The famous iris data set, for example, intuitively consists only of 2 clusters (but 3 classes).

For evaluation and all that, **check existing questions and answers, please**.

Comment: can you please explain why cluster labels and class labels are diffrent.If they are diffrent we can not use class labels for computing external cluster validation parameters, is it like that?

Comment: You can use random numbers for computing external validation parameters... it will return a result; but the result may not be as helpful as if you had real clusters labeled. I'm not saying that clusters are orthogonal to classes, but there is not necessarily a 1:1 correspondence. Cluster evaluation is black magic. Class labels is just the best we've found so far.